# How to all qr codes which are in images and save in android

Tags: android, qr-code

I need to get all Qr code from user image (the image having QR Code in it) and have to show in list (also need to read that code and need to save as image )

(i have image which is having qr codes so, i need detect those qr codes from that image and have to show in a listview (with qr code and scaned code text))

Please help me find the best libraries to get it.